# Is there a way I can connect content with multiple divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure how to ask this question so below is an visualization of what I want to achieve.
Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify!

**Clarification:**
At slide one, image 01 and image 02 are visible. Only when the person clicks on the images does the text and title div become visible. More importantly, the text box must be coherent with the page-wrapper. For example, if I were to set the text div to `float:right`, it will float on the right side of the page-wrapper.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to use [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp)?

Comment: hi @Joe not sure if that's the function I'm looking for... I'm thinking along the lines of a class or id that represents a corresponding image and text? ex: project01 = image01, title01, text01 and project02 = image02, title02, text02.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some javascript to get this behaviour i think. You can try something like this:

Everything in a little bit pseudo code.

HTML:

```
<img src="..." class="img1 clickImage">
<img src="..." class="img2 clickImage">

<div class="imageTitles">
    <div class="img1 imgTitle">TITLETEXT</div>
    <div class="img2 imgTitle">TITLETEXT</div>
</div>

<div class="imageInformations">
    <div class="img1 imgInformation">INFORMATION img1</div>
    <div class="img2 imgInformation">INFORMATION img2</div>
</div>
```

And some jQuery:

```
jQuery('.clickImage').on('click', function() {
    var imgNumber = jQuery(this).getClass().replace('clickImage', '');
    jQuery('imageTitles .imgTitle').hide(); //hide all image Titles
    jQuery('imageTitles .imgTitle.' + imgNumber).show(); //show title for e.g. img1

    //repeat this for imgInformation
});
```

Everything a little bit rough, but i hope it gives you an idea what you need to do.

---

EDIT:
Code now looks like this:

HTML:

```
<img src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mcepyv1Qfv1ru82ue.jpg" class="img1 clickImage">
<img src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mcf11pk4nj1ru82ue.jpg" class="img2 clickImage">
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div class="imageTitles">
    <div class="img1 imgTitle">TITLETEXT</div>
    <div class="img2 imgTitle">TITLETEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="imageInformations">
    <div class="img1 imgInformation">INFORMATION img1</div>
    <div class="img2 imgInformation">INFORMATION img2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('.imageTitles .imgTitle').hide(); 
jQuery('.imageInformations .imgInformation').hide(); 

jQuery('.clickImage').on('click', function () {
  var imgNumber = jQuery(this).attr("class").replace('clickImage', '');
  jQuery('.imageTitles .imgTitle').hide(); //hide all image Titles
  jQuery('.imageTitles .imgTitle.' + imgNumber).show(); //show title for e.g. img1    
  jQuery('.imageInformations .imgInformation').hide();
  jQuery('.imageInformations .imgInformation.' + imgNumber).show(); 
});
```

Comment: Hi @der vampyr, thank you for your suggestion. however, my javascript knowledge isn't at peak yet. do you mind checking out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/jzkpweyv/

Comment: Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzkpweyv/1/) you just need to position title and information like you want by css.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you! It all makes perfect sense. I have marked your answer as the correct one.

Comment: I played around with your code, but I'm wondering if one more feature can be added to this javascript. Is it possible so that once one image is clicked, 1) information pops out and 2) the background fades away to a low opacity so that the information and image is in full focus? http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/dshe6b7f/2/

Comment: You can use opacity for the other images. (dont know what else can be on your page, that could need opacity. If there are only other images you should be fine with this: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dshe6b7f/3/) otherwise you maybe need another pagestructure.

Comment: ah, I'm thinking maybe this will be a better reference point: here is the previous javascript I was working on: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/nvwzgus0/10/ . I got the function right (I think), but the problem was how the image `.object-text` couldn't stay within the page-wrap. is there anyway these two can be somehow combined together?

Comment: I mean, ultimately I would want to be able to group a connected image, information, and title by one class or link, and have everything else structured. for example  `<div class="objectTitles">
           <div class="object01 objectTitle">TITLETEXT</div>
           <div class="object02 objectTitle">TITLETEXT</div>
       </div>`

Comment: You have to seperate the text boxes from the images. So you can position the textboxes with position absolute at a fixed point. Dont use to much float.

Comment: Right, but once the text box and image separates, doesn't that mean it'll loose the connectivity since both image and text box is in a div like object01 or object02? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with this, but I'm trying the best I can to understand—would you be so kind and demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64939/discussion-between-der-vampyr-and-kenhimself).

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1) with every thing static, ie info about image is already available in the page in different div's. 
 ex: working

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.switch').hide();
 });
 function myInfo(myId)
 {
  $('.switch').hide();
  $('#title'+myId).show();
  $('#description'+myId).show();
 }
</script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <!-- Images -->
   <img onclick="return myInfo('1')" id='image1' height="60" width="60" src="http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/52cddfb169beddee2a6c2246/the-29-coolest-us-air-force-images-of-the-year.jpg" alt="Image1"><br/>
   <img onclick="return myInfo('2')" id='image1' height="60" width="60" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6I83EILo3XKIsqZ-0Q5JAEw38xGzsy1g_iKImqjBrMVaOHYb4Zg" alt="Image2">
  </td>
  <td>
   <div id="title1" class="switch"> Image 1</div>
   <div id="title2" class="switch"> Image 2</div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div id="description1" class="switch"> Information about Image 1 </div>
   <div id="description2" class="switch"> Information about Image 2 </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

2) You can achieve this using AJAX calls for image information, in this case only 1 div for title and 1 for info is enough i you want to use else 1 div is enough.  On click of image make an AJAX call to get the image info and display it in the div.

These are 2 ways and there are many more.

Comment: There is a litte copy paste issue. You got two times the image1 id.

Comment: Hi @sunil goli , thank you for your suggestion! Do you mind taking a look at my [http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/KumcX/1846/](jsfiddle) not sure if I'm doing this right...?

Comment: Try it in your system. I have tried (jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/KumcX/1846) its working, but alignment is wrong.